# Sharepoint Designer 2013 - Cannot create workflow

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

Has anybody encountered the error below in creating SharePoint 2010 workflows in SharePoint Designer 2013?

"The list of workflow actions on the server references an assembly that does not exist. Some actions will not be available. The assembly strong name is Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c. Contact your server administrator for more information."

I have already tried the following:

1. Delete the following folders: (workaround suggested by Microsoft)
   C:\users\\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SharePoint Designer\ProxyAssemblyCache
   C:\users\\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Web Server Extensions\Cache
   C:\users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache
2. Installed a number hotfixes that could potentially solve this bug (but did not)
3. Uninstalled/installed/repaired SharePoint Foundation + SPD 2013 quite a few times

It worked for a few times when I first tried the workaround but when I edited the workflow, the error kept coming up and I couldn't even open the workflow, much less create another one.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps given in the below link and may be you can solve your problem.

Go to your hive folder:

Then into Template\1033\workflow

and find WSS.ACTIONS

Inside there will be a reference to a custom DLL, find it and remove it and your designer should start working again.

Make sure you take a backup of the file first.

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/68769/sharepoint-2010-sharepoint-designer-notification-the-list-of-workflow-actions

Thanks

Comment: Hi SigarDave, the problem is I don't have a custom DLL, it's referring to Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions and Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.